# How to correctly scroll an UICollectionView to an off screen row when UIViewController is presented?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have always wondered if there is a "proven" way of implementing the following scenario.

- Present UIViewController which contains UICollectionView
- Scroll the UICollectionView to its last row (or random offscreen row)

I have searched and tested multiple approaches but I have not see any "official" proven way of implementing this. Has anyone had any luck with implementing this in a clean way, preferable in Swift.

Comment: Have any of your tests worked as expected?

Comment: They did but all of them involved more logic than I feel was necessary. I now tried the `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` and it does work perfect so this is way better than what I was experimenting with. Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60544491/3801632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the viewdidload add this code

`let selectedIndex = arr.count - 1`  //last index of arr where arr is your //dataSource array

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: selectedIndex, section: 0)  
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks I totally missed `performBatchUpdates`, works way better than what I tried.